# Accessing the content of events in Javascript?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get a print out of the events my cloud function is privy to. I tried console.log(event)in the Atom console but I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'
at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
at Module._resolveFilename
```

I'm not familiar with Javascript or Atom, so I don't know why I'm not getting the expected behaviors, my guess is that I need to authorize the script that is trying to access my secure backend on Firebase.

Here's my cloud function so far:

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');

 const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/
iMessenger/{Messages}/{id}').onWrite(event => {

//I really want to see all that's inside of 'event'. How do I see this info??
console.log(event)
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title:'New message arrived',
    body:'Hello World',
    badge:'1',
    sound:'default',
    }
};
  return admin.database().ref('/iMessenger/{Messages}/{id}/toUserDisplayName').once('value').then(allToken => {
    if (allToken.val()){
      const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {

   });
  };
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using `console.dir(event)` will list every available method and parameter within `event`

Comment: I tried that but got this error: module.js:457 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'(…), @mast3rd3mon, what software are you using to run your javascript? I'm using Atom and it's not quite like using xCode which I'm rather comfortable with.

Comment: the error is unrelated to printing every method and property of `event`. the error you have is to do with a missing file/module. as for what i use to run the code, it will not matter

Comment: I see. Any suggestion on how I could find this missing module? After already going through the terminal and installing googleCouldFunction with this command: npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator and npm install -g firebase-tools. I expected the necessary modules to be present in the automatically generate javascript files, Abd firebase was even able to upload my cloud function, so up until now everything seemed to working okay. @mast3rd3mon, what else needs to be done to get the modules?

Comment: i havent used that module before so im not too sure

Answer (score 0):

Console.log(event) shows up in your cloud function logs in firebase. And the missing module was because my editor couldn’t exactly interface with the firebase modules I figure, as firebase accepts my functions and the notification  are coming through; a testament to successful implementation.